# Add express server to react-scripts on start

Tags: express, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm using create react app and want to add a custom express server to begin when I launch my app. How can I get this working with react-scripts. At the moment this server file isn't being run.

Comment: That's outside the scope of CRA.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the concurrently package. This package allows you to run multiple scripts concurrently, which is useful for running the frontend and backend at the same time.

Then you could add a command to your package.json file, something like this dev example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "server": "node server.js",
  "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start\" \"npm run server\""
}
```

Comment: Is this the official way of doing this?

Comment: @chackerian I don't know how official it is, but I have used this package for similar things and thought of it when you asked your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely related but CRA (create-react-app) is on its way out, I would look into Vite for creating react apps. More on topic, I usually split screen my terminal in VSCode and run the server on one side with nodemon and my react app on the other side

Comment: How come? Are the developers leaving?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).